# Movie about a boy who was born old and grew young

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a non-animated movie about a boy who was born old, but grew young and dies as a baby.

He fell in love, but the girl grew old normally and dies, while this guy grows younger and finally dies as a newborn.

Comment: Not to be confused with "Jack", with Robin Williams, as I first thought. He was born normally, but aged 4x faster, so the opposite of this question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is  *[The Curious Case of Benjamin Button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curious_Case_of_Benjamin_Button_(film))*.

> The film stars Brad Pitt as a man who ages in reverse and Cate
>   Blanchett as the love interest throughout his life.

Comment: i'll just mark this as the right one...even though @Edlothiad gave the right answer first

Comment: @THEEPICGUY: As a minor remark then, the guy dies first (the girl lived to tell about his death in the physical state of a newborn; she was the narrator of the movie).

Answer (score 20):

As pointed out by @Edlothiad in the comments (but him being "very content with it as a comment"), this is *The Curious Case of Benjamin Button* (2008), based on a 1922 short story of the same name. OP has apparently indicated that was it in [another comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213709/movie-about-a-boy-who-was-born-old-and-grew-young/213718#comment583591_213709).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0421715):

> Benjamin Button, a baby that was born looking like an old man, is taken in by a nurse at an old folks home. Over the years as Benjamin got "older" he appeared to get younger. As he lives at the home, he meets Daisy, a beautiful young girl the same age. He falls in love with her, knowing the relationship will always look strange. Will his disability get in the way of true love? Or will it set him free?

Comment: ""The Curious Case of Benjamin Button" is a short story written by **F. Scott Fitzgerald**. First published in Collier's Magazine on May 27, 1922" I'd no idea he tried this genre. Read it ages ago. A great story, well worth the read.